# "This page isn't redirecting properly" on one particular site with one particular user

Tags: apache, django

I administer a web site (https://fury.games) and one of our users is reporting that they cannot load the main page and get the following error:

[image: This page isn't redirecting properly]

I cannot reproduce the error, no other users have reported this error, and the user claims other web sites work for him.

Any ideas?  What can we try?  How might we go about debugging this?  The site is based on apache/django.

Comment: Maybe he just needs to clear his browsing cache.

Comment: The browser may have an issue with its local cache copy, as mentioned, its one of those things that the tech support, "shut it down and restart," work on. However, because there is a limit on the number of 301 redirects a browser will do. If possible, it would be a good idea to ask what page he hit the link from ... the browser may report a problem, if a 301 that points to a 301, which points to a 301, to a 301, to a 301 ... IE http:// www.example.com 301s to https:// www.example.com 301s to https:// example.com ... to fix 301 http:// www.example.com to https:// example.com